# Using forward slashes ('/') in URI templates without encoding

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, uri

I've got a RESTful WCF service that acts as a file store. Since there can be any number of directories and sub-directories, I'm trying to let the users access them by simply putting the file path into the URL. Is there a way I can do this without requiring the user to encode the slashes?

For example, what I want is a URI template of `Files/{path}` that can be accessed like `http://localhost:8000/Files/folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/file.jpg`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"encode the slashes"_? Can you provide an example on 1) what the user should write if he had to encode, 2) what you would like him to write, 3) what result you would like to get by reading the user input.

Comment: Encoding the slashes is necessary since the service would otherwise interpret the slashes as being part of a URI rather than part of a parameter. With the former, it would return a 404 since it won't be able to find a matching URI template. With encoding, the example URL above would look like this: `http://localhost:8000/Files%2Ffolder1%2Fsubfolder2%2Fsubfolder3%2Ffile.jpg`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put a * at the end of your uri template.  Inside your operation you can interpret the rest of the uri that matches to * as your file path.

Comment: I changed my URI from `Files/{path}` to `Files/{*path}`, and it's working fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to use URL rewriting techniques to accomplish this. if using .net 4 use Route table.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid not understanding right. Would the following work?

- Let the user enter something like `folder1/subfolder2/subfolder3/file.jpg` in `path` variable.
- Perform: `String encodedPath = path.Replace("/", "%2F");`

Comment: That would work, but the idea is to let users access the file without having to encode the slashes. This makes for a cleaner URL and slightly easier access (i.e. direct link through a browser's address bar).